# list comprehension or shorter form that achieves rgb to hex for colour palette

Tags: python, split, hex, list-comprehension, rgb

How could i convert this for loop into a list comprehension ?

```
rgb_arr = [[217, 180, 131], [242, 228, 221], [132, 174, 221], [203, 135, 74], [28, 49, 21],
[154, 179, 101], [213, 200, 186], [87, 143, 51]]

hex_palette = []
for rgb in rgb_arr:
    col_hex = '#' + hex(rgb[0]).split('x')[-1] + hex(rgb[1]).split('x')[-1] + hex(rgb[2]).split('x')[-1]
    hex_palette.append(col_hex)
print(hex_palette)
```

The resulting hex list from the print statement should look like this

```
['#d9b483', '#f2e4dd', '#84aedd', '#cb874a', '#1c3115', '#9ab365', '#d5c8ba', '#578f33']
```

Is there a pythonic way of reducing the repetition of this part ?:-

```
hex(rgb[0]).split('x')[-1] +
```

Comment: ['#' + hex(rgb[0]).split('x')[-1] + hex(rgb[1]).split('x')[-1] + hex(rgb[2]).split('x')[-1] for rgb in rgb_arr]

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way to do this is to use string formatting, in a list copmrehension or not:

```
[f'#{a:02x}{b:02x}{c:02x}' for a,b,c in rgb_arr]
```

Or just:

```
result = []
for a,b,c in rgb_arr:
    result.append(f'#{a:02x}{b:02x}{c:02x}')
```

Comment: OP *specifically* asked for a list comprehension (as in the first part of your answer).

Comment: @ScottHunter yes, so what? I'm showing them the equivalent for-loop so that they can understand how they work.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use list comprehension and f-strings:

```
hex_palette = [f"#{rgb[0]:02x}{rgb[1]:02x}{rgb[2]:02x}" for rgb in rgb_arr]
```

On the formatting the initial `0` means to fill up the empty spaces with `0`-s, the `2` means fill up until two characters and the `x` means use hexadecimal.

Or, if you are using an older Python like 3.5, you can use string formatting instead of f-strings:

```
hex_palette = ["#{rgb[0]:02x}{rgb[1]:02x}{rgb[2]:02x}".format(rgb=rgb) for rgb in rgb_arr]
```

Answer (score 1):

One more variation:

```
[("#%02x%02x%02x"%tuple(b)) for b in rgb_arr]
```

(to take care of values < 10).

Answer (score 1):

could also use matplotlib built in functions...

```
from matplotlib.colors import to_hex
```

you can either normalize your RGB ints before hand or just convert it to a numpy array and do this:

```
rgb_arr = np.array(rgb_arr)
hex_palette = [to_hex(rgb/255) for rgb in rgb_arr]
```

output:

```
['#d9b483', '#f2e4dd', '#84aedd', '#cb874a', '#1c3115', '#9ab365', '#d5c8ba', '#578f33']
```

Comment: FYI - can also support an alpha value .. https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.to_hex.html

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to minimize code repetition, you can also map the color values to the `format` method of the formatting string:

```
[f"#{''.join(map('{:02x}'.format, c))}" for c in rgb_arr]
```

Answer (score 0):

The lazy way using [webcolors](https://pypi.org/project/webcolors/):

```
from webcolors import rgb_to_hex
rgb_arr = [[217, 180, 131], [242, 228, 221], [132, 174, 221], [203, 135, 74], [28, 49, 21], [154, 179, 101], [213, 200, 186], [87, 143, 51]]
[rgb_to_hex(x) for x in rgb_arr]
```

---

```
pip install webcolors
```